# Javascript: node.onclick call a function not working

Tags: javascript

I use a loop through the node elements to get the ID from the clicked element. Until then all good and it works. Now I want to call an another function in my class & get this error:

this._PreLoad is not defined at HTMLElement.s.onclick

```
this._joinnews.forEach((node) => {
    node.onclick = function(){
        const requestData = `newsid=${node.id}`;
        // some code // 
        this._PreLoad(true); // ERROR
        // _PreLoad(true); not working
        // this._PreLoad(true).bind(this); not working (I am not yet familiar with the bind function)
    }
});
```

Are the functions inside a node loop unknown ?

Comment: `this` in the click handler refers to the cliked element. Make the handler also an arrow function, that way the correct `this` is bound to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct place to `bind` `this` is here:

```
node.onclick = function() {
    const requestData = `newsid=${node.id}`;
    // some code // 
    this._PreLoad(true);
}.bind(this); // bind here!
```

Alternatively, use an arrow function which preserves `this` as whatever it was at the time of the function declaration:

```
node.onclick = () => {
    const requestData = `newsid=${node.id}`;
    // some code // 
    this._PreLoad(true);
}
```